# Docker build failure with "Segmentation fault" when "npm run build"

Tags: docker, npm, build

I'm new to docker containers and learning as we go. When I try building an image that is a Next.js app with a crawler, I get the below error.

I'm able to successfully run "npm run build" locally without issue, it does compile.

The command I'm using is this one (with ENV=production as only arg):

```
docker build -t europe-west9-docker.pkg.dev/chwai/chwai-docker-repository/chwai-backend-crawler:v1 $(for i in `cat deployment/args/chwai-backend-crawler.sh`; do out+="--build-arg $i " ; done; echo $out;out="") chwai-backend-crawler/
```

This is the response I get

```
[+] Building 5.6s (11/16)                                                                                    docker:desktop-linux
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                            0.0s
 => => transferring context: 105B                                                                                            0.0s
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                         0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 1.38kB                                                                                       0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:slim                                                                 1.0s
 => [builder 1/5] FROM docker.io/library/node:slim@sha256:11f66bf5d0842fe1f87457fabe62aa3bbcfbb739d231a39e67597af22d8f5ffd   0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                            0.0s
 => => transferring context: 5.34kB                                                                                          0.0s
 => CACHED [builder 2/5] WORKDIR /app                                                                                        0.0s
 => CACHED [builder 3/5] COPY . .                                                                                            0.0s
 => CACHED [dependencies 3/4] COPY package.json package-lock.json ./                                                         0.0s
 => CACHED [dependencies 4/4] RUN npm install                                                                                0.0s
 => CACHED [builder 4/5] COPY --from=dependencies /app/node_modules ./node_modules                                           0.0s
 => ERROR [builder 5/5] RUN npm run build                                                                                    4.5s
------                                                                                                                            
 > [builder 5/5] RUN npm run build:                                                                                               
0.763                                                                                                                             
0.763 > chwai-backend-crawler@0.1.0 build                                                                                         
0.763 > next build                                                                                                                
0.763                                                                                                                             
1.254 Attention: Next.js now collects completely anonymous telemetry regarding usage.
1.256 This information is used to shape Next.js' roadmap and prioritize features.
1.256 You can learn more, including how to opt-out if you'd not like to participate in this anonymous program, by visiting the following URL:
1.256 https://nextjs.org/telemetry
1.256 
1.394 info  - Linting and checking validity of types...
3.650 info  - Creating an optimized production build...
4.461 Segmentation fault
4.464 npm notice 
4.464 npm notice New minor version of npm available! 9.7.2 -> 9.8.0
4.465 npm notice Changelog: <https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v9.8.0>
4.465 npm notice Run `npm install -g npm@9.8.0` to update!
4.465 npm notice 
------
Dockerfile:13
--------------------
  11 |     COPY . .
  12 |     COPY --from=dependencies /app/node_modules ./node_modules
  13 | >>> RUN npm run build
  14 |     
  15 |     # Production image, copy all the files and run next
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c npm run build" did not complete successfully: exit code: 139
```

Any suggestion on how I can fix it?

Not much as I am stuck unfortunately.